# Rotate with the z-x'-z'' Euler sequence with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I want to rotate an object using the z-x'-z'' convention of Euler using Animation Nodes.

[image]

What I've thought that I need to do is to rotate along the local axis of the object, first around the z, then around the x and then around the z again. If I create a rotation matrix, select the transformation orientation to local and then rotate first on the z, then on the x and then on the z I get the result that I want for the first two rotations, the last is done in the the original z, not in the modified local axis, so I can't use that:
[image]

Is there a way to do the three rotations in local axis in the specific order using only animation nodes? I have other objects in my node tree that I don't want to transform along their local axis, so I rather prefer to avoid to select the local transformation orientation and do it purely in animation nodes:

[image]

Thanks! I hope that I explain myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Combine Matrices` for doing any complex transformation.

[image]

Comment: Oh, thanks! And for doing a local transformation in Animation Nodes?  I have other objects in my node tree that I don't want to transform along their local axis, so I rather prefer to avoid to select the local transformation orientation and do it purely in animation nodes